# How to Declare Global Multidimensional array Variable

Tags: android, arrays, variables, multidimensional-array, global

i'm using Global variable for my app and i need to know How to set/get the variable myarray below?

```
  public class Global extends Application {
      private String name;
      private String  [][][] myarray=new String[10][10][10];  //<-----

      public String getName() {

          return name;
      }

      public void setName(String aName) {
          name = aName;
      }

    //<--- set/get for myarray ?
  }
```

and in my MainActivity how can i get/set the value for myarray?

```
  Global g = (Global)getApplication();
  String data=g.getName();
  g.setName("test");
  //<-  get/set for myarray ?
```

Answer (score 0):

You need generate getter setter for your array;

whenever you want to user it just call

```
((ApplicationName) getApplicationContext()).getMyarray();
```

for set you need to pass the object

```
((ApplicationName) getApplicationContext()).setMyarray(new String[10][10][10]);
```